# Media web part unable to embed videos from Videos or Stream?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, office-365-video-portal

For reasons too long to explain my intranet still runs on old Web Part Pages. With this type of pages even when using the Media Web Part, it is impossible to embed a video from Videos or Stream.

The embed link provided is not accepted as a 'video from address' as well as the link provided from the generated email.

The link provided is (I have added spaces)

https://domain.com/portals/hub/ _layouts/15/PointPublishing.aspx?app=video&p=p&chid=f1c8db25-485a-4b28-b606-0cd3db0647db&vid=b8f40cfa-0c56-45b8-889e-e8da8d1113a8&from=2

How it is possible to retrieve a URL that can be used with the Media web part?

Also the direct link from stream (which starts from web.microsoftstream.com) is not accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This might seem like too obvious an answer, but have you tried just putting the embed link (from the video viewer on Stream) into a Script Editor Web Part, or via Ribbon > Embed Code?

I've done this plenty of times and it works fine, the embed HTML code should take care of the player widget without needing to embed it in another web part.

Comment: This is what is done now and it causes authentication problems (even with single sign-on) so that random people at random times get on the screen 'this video is set to private'. From experience I never got the same from the media web part, therefore I think using the content editor web part is not the right thing to do unless desperate